# ODE $x\sqrt{1+p^2}=p$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

This exercise in (non linear ODE. of first order and higher degree - solve in x)

Solve ODE $x\sqrt{1+p^2}=p$

My try:

$x={p\over \sqrt{1+p^2}}$

Derivative for $y$:

${dx\over dy}={1\over {{1+p^2}{\sqrt{1+p^2}}}}{dp\over dy}$

$p={dy\over dx}$ so ${dx\over dy}={1\over p}$

${1\over p}={1\over {{1+p^2}{\sqrt{1+p^2}}}}{dp\over dy}$

$dy={p\over {{1+p^2}{\sqrt{1+p^2}}}}dp$

How can I complete this, what's the integration?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry i mean $x={p\over \sqrt{1+p^2}}$ @Chinny84

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
x\sqrt{1+y'^2} = y'
$$
If $p = y'$
then we have
$$
x^2 + x^2y'^2 = y'^2\implies y' = \frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=-\frac{d}{dx}\sqrt{1-x^2}
$$
so we have
$$
y = -\sqrt{1-x^2} + C
$$

Comment: And $\pm=+$. $ $